# Reading Johann Georg Burkhardt's profession

Tags: germany, palaeography, kurrent

I cannot parse the last word of this line about Johann Georg Burkhardt.

Can anyone help with his profession?

[image]

Comment: What is the source of this document?  Having that may be able to help potential answerers view the line you cannot read in context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading up a bit on tanning techniques, I am fairly confident the word in question is *Weißgerbers*, i.e. the genitive case of *Weißgerber*. This term denotes a tanner (*Gerber*) operating with mineral salts, it seems primarily aluminum salts, in order to produce leather of higher quality and lighter color (*weiß* = white) than more common tanning techniques.

Addendum: The corresponding English word seems to be tawer, the technique itself is called tawing.

Comment: Many thanks!  The area had mainly farmers, leather workers, and a salt mine, so that also makes a lot of sense.